# Is there any way the QA LLM will know that user input query has been used or even similar to the one it has been trained on?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, chatbot, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I would like to know if there is any way to know or might get a hint on whether there is a way of knowing that certain query that user throws(or might be similar) to QA LLM that it has been used as train set or no?